# replace values to a dataframe column from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace values from a dataframe column with values from another based on a third one and keep the rest of the values from the first df.

```
# df1
country   name   value
romania   john   100
russia    emma   200
sua       mark   300
china     jack   400

# df2
name   value
emma   2
mark   3
```

Desired result:

```
# df3
country   name   value
romania   john   100
russia    emma   2
sua       mark   3
china     jack   400
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be as follows:

- Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on column `name` and turn `df2` into a Series for mapping by setting its index to `name` ([`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)).
- Next, chain [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to replace `NaN` values with original values from `df.value` (i.e. whenever mapping did not result in a match) and assign to `df['value']`.

```
df['value'] = df['name'].map(df2.set_index('name')['value']).fillna(df['value'])

print(df)

   country  name  value
0  romania  john  100.0
1   russia  emma    2.0
2      sua  mark    3.0
3    china  jack  400.0
```

N.B. The result will now contain floats. If you prefer `integers`, chain [`.astype(int)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be using [pandas.DataFrame.Update](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df1.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('name'))
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

   name  country  value
0  john  romania  100.0
1  emma   russia    2.0
2  mark      sua    3.0
3  jack    china  400.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```py
df3          = df1.merge(df2, on = 'name', how = 'left')
df3['value'] = df3.value_y.fillna(df3.value_x) 
df3.drop(['value_x', 'value_y'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

#    country  name  value
# 0  romania  john  100.0
# 1   russia  emma    2.0
# 2      sua  mark    3.0
# 3    china  jack  400.0
```

Reproducible data:

```py
df1=pd.DataFrame({'country':['romania','russia','sua','china'],'name':['john','emma','mark','jack'],'value':[100,200,300,400]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'name':['emma','mark'],'value':[2,3]})
```